# Laravel - Eloquent group by

Tags: laravel, group-by, eloquent

When I use group by, the results get grouped but not all of them are returned. Here I have six results but I only get five results. So basically `room_id = 17` gets the entry `103` and entry `106` is not returned.

[image: Data]

Here is what I am doing:

```
$prices = $hotel->prices()->groupBy('room_id')->get();
```

Comment: Of course that is what a `GROUP BY` does. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @ThomasVanderVeen I want get five results, one of them contains two results since they both have the same `room_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way of grouping the like you desire. You can use `groupBy()` on the collection eloquent returns when it executes the query. The trick is to `groupBy()` after the database retrieving. Check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-groupby) for more info.

An example would look like this:

```
$prices = $hotel->prices()->get(); // Returns a Collection of results

$prices = $prices->groupBy('room_id'); // Grouped by room_id
```

This will result in a collection that looks like:

```
[
    '39' => [
        // 1 row
    ],
    '40' => [
        // 1 row
    ],
    '17' => [
        // 2 rows
    ], 
    .....
]
```

The keys of this array will represent the room_id. On every key is this array will be another array containing the rows with the specified room_id.

Hope this helps :)